# Physics of tidal locking: can the process be underdamped?

Tags: planets, rotation, tidal-effect, satellites

Is it possible for a satellite undergoing the process to overshoot the required rotation rate for tidal locking?   For example, if its rotation rate is being slowed, can it become slower than it needs for tidal locking and then oscillate back as it is torqued the other way?   If it can happen, how long can such an oscillation persist?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand the phenomenon (and it's a little outside my wheelhouse, so I may be putting my foot in my mouth), tidal locking is entirely a result of damping - the fluid friction and solid stresses that convert rotational energy into heat because of the gradient in gravitational field strength.

So, if you take away the damping, there's no effect at all - there would be no slowing of the rotation rate.  If you reduce the damping (by making the satellite stiffer, or moving it further away from the parent, etc), it would just tidally lock more slowly.

A linear analogy would be a book sliding across the floor and coming to a stop.  You wouldn't think that if you took away the friction, it might overshoot that spot then come back.

Comment: This is an interesting way to look at it, and you may be right.   But in your example, the energy is lost as heat so can't get (easily) converted back into mechanical energy.   In the tidal locking case, rotational energy is converted into a change in rotation of the primary and/or a change in orbital altitude to preserve angular momentum.   Couldn't that go in reverse?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I think this answer is right -- planetary rotation is not a harmonic oscillator, so the notions of over/under/critical damping don't apply. The friction analogy is spot on (although I will admit, this is also outside of my domain). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) gives a reference [to a paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006%2Ficar.1996.0117) that is probably exactly on point for what you want to know. It's where the expression for $t_{lock}$ comes from on that page.

Comment: @ThePopMachine, in both cases, the energy is lost as heat, and in both cases, linear and angular momentum is conserved.  Instead of a book on a floor, imagine a book sliding across a rolling toy car.  The speeds of both change to reduce relative speed to zero.  In the process, KE is lost while momentum is conserved. Once locked, the book won't start sliding again even though the car might have sped up.

Comment: @BowlOfRed:  Again, you guys may be right, I'm just not confident.   Imagine this extreme case and tell me what's wrong with the thought experiment:

Comment: Imagine you have a rigid oblong body in a perfectly circular orbit.   And say it's nearly tidally locked so the major axis points nearly toward the primary and the rotation nearly matches the revolution.   Then would you agree it experiences a restoring torque due to gravity pulling on the closer portion of the satellite that wants to keep the major axis pointed at the large body?   Won't this oscillate?

Comment: Ah, yes - if the body were already nearly tidally locked, I agree that the major axis would wiggle back and forth like a pendulum.  But that's a little different from tidal locking.  If that perfectly rigid body had enough rotational energy to complete a full rotation on its axis, then it would continue rotating forever at the same speed; the net angular momentum imparted by the gravity of the primary would be zero over the course of a whole revolution.

Comment: @Brionius:   Okay, I see what you're saying, although I think there is still a small net torque because of the lag in application of the torque due to relativity -- IIRC, this effect has a name -- someone else will have to supply the term.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "oscillate back".  I believe that we were thinking of different things here.

A better analogy might be a vertical circular pendulum (one that is free to go all the way around).  If we give the pendulum a lot of energy, it will rotate all the way around the axis.  If there is friction, then the pendulum will eventually not have enough energy to make it over the top and it will swing back and forth at the bottom.

A planet becoming tidally locked will behave similarly.

When you mentioned "oscillate back faster", I imagined you meant that it might rotate around in the other direction (completely) or pick up speed in the other direction.  It won't do that.  It will oscillate with decreasing amplitude.  If that's the oscillation you mean, then yes it can, and with minimal damping it can persist indefinitely (like a minimally damped pendulum).

Comment: Thanks -- the use of the word 'faster' was at a minimum confusing.   I was probably thinking of the reversal of direction of rotation when I wrote 'faster'.   At any rate, I removed it.